# Can any of existing IoC containers create the lazy proxy classes dynamically?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, lifetime

I study different DI patterns.
And now I interested in the lazy life-time implementation.
For example, I want to write a proxy class that hides the factory behind a service's interface.
Can any of existing IoC containers (.NET) create this kind of proxy class dynamically at runtime?

```
interface IService
{
    void Foo();
    void Bar();
}

class ServiceFactoryProxy : IService
{
    private readonly Func<IService> _factory;

    public ServiceFactoryProxy(Func<IService> factory)
    {
        if (factory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("factory");
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _factory().Foo();
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        _factory().Foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it can be done in Castle:

http://litemedia.info/lazy-loading-property-with-castle-dynamicproxy2

Answer (score 1):

Unity does this out of the box. You declare a dependency of type `Func<IService>` in your constructor (like you did with `ServiceFactoryProxy`) and tell Unity how it should resolve `IService`. The container will generate the delegate for you.

---

**Update**

That proxy looks like an encapsulation of [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx).

If that is your intention you might want to have a look at [this extension for Unity](http://pwlodek.blogspot.de/2010/05/lazy-and-ienumerable-support-comes-to.html).

As far as I know Unity 3.0 will have support for .NET4 so I expect something similar to turn up as part of Unity with the next release.

---

**Update2**

It took me a while but I finished the lazy proxy feature. It generates IL code that looks like this

```
public class MyContract_LazyInstantiationProxy : IMyContract
{
  private readonly Lazy<IMyContract> instance;
  public MyContract_LazyInstantiationProxy(Func<IMyContract> factory)
  {
    Guard.AssertNotNull(factory, "factory");
    this.instance = new Lazy<IMyContract>(factory);
  }
  public IMyContract Instance
  {
    get { return this.instance.Value; }
  }
  public string Foo(Bar bar)
  {
    return this.Instance.Foo(bar);
  }
}
```

So you get the performance of hand-coded lazy proxies but they will be generated dynamically for you.

Have a look at the [TecX project on codeplex](http://tecx.codeplex.com). The lazy proxy generation can be found in the source code of *TecX.Unity.Proxies*. A sample on how to use it is in the according test project *TecX.Unity.Proxies.Test*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was referring to the dynamic generation of class ServiceFactoryProxy ...

Comment: @DmitriyStartsev Got your question wrong. Maybe the update is closer to what you want.

Comment: Maybe it's because of my poor English skills... I am sorry if it is. In that example Lazy<ILogger> is an example of a leaky abstraction. Consumer of ILogger shouldn't know anything about it's initialization (is it lazy or not). It should depend on ILogger instead. Concrete implementation of the ILogger can provide us lazy initialization of logger using the proxy class. Read more this http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/ComposeObjectGraphsWithConfidence.aspx My question was how to generate this proxy class at runtime.

Comment: @DmitriyStartsev Thanks for the clarification! I missed the point about the leaky abstraction although I read that blog post by Mark Seemann a while ago. I'm looking forward to porting that functionality to Unity :)

Comment: @DmitriyStartsev If you are still looking for a solution to that problem you might want to have a look at my second update.