# Expensive Object Creation with Dependency Injection

Tags: model-view-controller, dependency-injection, unit-of-work

I'm new to DI and I am working on an MVC project where a controller is injected a [UnitOfWork](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) and this UnitOfWork contains Repositories for each entity type in my domain.  Using [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx) as a guide, I originally had something like

```
public IRepository<Employee> Employees {
    get {
        if (_employees == null) {
            _employees = new SqlRepository<Employee>(_context);
        }
        return _employees;
    }
}
```

However, I thought it'd be nice to inject the Repository, for example:

```
public SqlUnitOfWork(IRepository<Employee> employees)
{
    this.Employees = employees;
}
```

But what if creating the SqlRepository is very expensive.  Not every controller action uses every repository.  Before I changed to DI, each repository would only be created if they were accessed.  However, now all repositories are created with the UnitOfWork.  I'm trying to determine whether or not it is worth it to inject SqlRepositories when I'm already in a SqlUnitOfWork? Or, should I follow the MSDN example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sub>I am not ASP.NET MVC user, but the ideas behind [dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) approach do not change. So, *take this with grain of salt*.</sub>

From your description, you are using several repositories with the unit of work, and you cannot decide whether to inject them or create within. The best course would be: **neither**.

When you are dealing with unknown number of same type of dependencies, it is smarter to instead inject a factory instance. Your `UnitOfWork` implementation then can request service from said factory.

The factory in this case would check, if such service has already been initialized. If such service has been initialized, you can just return it. If not, you initialize that service, cache it *(most likely in some array-like structure within the factory)* and return that instance.

---

**Some other notes**

- Neither repositories nor units of work should be exposed to controller. They are structures which are responsible for dealing with storage. You end up exposing internal details of model layer to the presentation layer. Basically, *your abstraction is leaking*.
- I would be careful about reading that tutorial. It seems that author of the article did not fully grasp the concept of DI. If you look at this bit of code:

  ```
  public class SqlUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {
      public SqlUnitOfWork() {
          var connectionString =
              ConfigurationManager
                  .ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringName]
                  .ConnectionString;
          _context = new ObjectContext(connectionString);
      }

      /* --- SNIP --- */

      readonly ObjectContext _context;
      const string ConnectionStringName = "EmployeeDataModelContainer";
  }
  ```

  You can see that the DB connection is initialized in the constructor, based on constant, that has been hardwired in the definition of `SqlUnitOfWork` class. *That's an extremely bad practice.*
- If you want to learn more about dependency injection of OOP practices in general, i would recommend you to [watch this lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) and lectures from same series.

Comment: I am actually injecting services (service layer) into my controller.  These services will then have the unit of work injected into them.  So, you and others are recommending injecting a unit of work factory into the services that are going into my constructor?

Comment: If each service can be dealing with multiple *unit-of-work* instances, then: yes, you should inject a factory. But, if every service works with its own single specific instance of unit-of-work, then you inject it directly in the constructor, when initializing service instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are right to be worried about injecting an expensive-to-create object.

Dependency Injection relies on being able to cheaply create and inject objects (some of which may never be used).  This is why it is a bad idea to perform "real work" in a constructor or when building the object graph.

The problem here is that `IRepository` is expensive to create.  If it's doing "real work" in the constructor, can you move that work later to just before it's needed? This is a bit like lazy evaluation.  This fixes the root cause of the problem.

Sometimes, that's not possible.  There are workarounds:

- Inject something that will give you an instance of IRepository (a factory)
- Implement the IRepository interface as LazyRepository.  LazyRepository has a member variable for the real, expensive to create repository.  In each method, you check if this variable is null. If it is, you create the real repository.  Then, each method delgates to the real repository.

Comment: I like the idea of a LazyRepository and it is simple enough to use in other generic places, when the need comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting factories for expensive dependencies means that the consumer of that dependency knows that there is one expensive implementation of the dependency's interface. If the consumer changes its implementation accordingly that is a leaky abstraction.

Have a look a [this blog post](http://outlawtrail.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/unity-generate-lazy-proxies-on-the-fly/). It shows how to generate a lazy proxy that implements your repository's interface on-the-fly using Unity.

[According to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757953/can-any-of-existing-ioc-containers-create-the-lazy-proxy-classes-dynamically) Castle Windsor can do the same.

Comment: I agree with your answer.  What approach do you take when the injected object has no interface. e.g. It is an expensive to create String? Such a String might come from a database or web service.  Seems like we are forced into the leaky abstraction then?

Comment: @WW. Expensive primitive objects... that never occurred to me.
You can inject a `Lazy<string>` instead of the `string`. But it smells a bit like the factory approach.

Comment: We inject Provider<T> which has a single method, T get().  But the fact that it's expensive leaks into the class it's injected into.